# Multiple pagination of arbitrary array of objects

Tags: paging

I have an array with this structure:

```
$things = array('term1' => array(Object, Object, ... Object),
                'term2' => array(Object, Object, ... Object),
                'term3' => array(Object, Object, ... Object),
                 .... etc...
```

I want to be able to generate output like:

```
Term1

* Object 1
* Object 2
* ... etc ...

 < 1, 2, 3 > (<-- that's pagination :D)

Term2

* Object 1
* Object 2
* ... etc ...

 < 1, 2, 3 >
```

Which each list of things paginated (assuming there are more than x of them).

Is there a way I can achieve this?

A template function I can pass each of the individual arrays of Objects into to get pagination?

If it matters, this is all taking place inside a block, in D7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Drupal Pagination with a Custom Query](http://treehouseagency.com/blog/fmitchell/2010/10/12/drupal-pagination-custom-query) for full code example

Comment: Cheers, the second example looks like that I want.